# Populate drop down menu from database

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu, jstl, jspx

I have this method in my controller to get all the created floors so that I can use it in creating a room record.

```html
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String create(@Valid Room room, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateEditForm(uiModel, room);
            return "rooms/create";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        roomService.saveRoom(room);
        return "redirect:/rooms/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(room.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }

 @RequestMapping(params = "form", produces = "text/html")
    public String createForm(Model uiModel) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, new Room());
        return "rooms/create";
    }





 void populateEditForm(Model uiModel, Room room) {
        uiModel.addAttribute("room", room);
        uiModel.addAttribute("floors", Floor.findAllFloors());
    }
```

Then, I originally have this code in my views page to display the floors in a dropdown list:

```html
<field:select field="floor"
id="c_ph_com_smesoft_hms_domain_Room_floor" itemValue="id"
items="${floors}" path="/floors" z="BO2RLJSaIYxNwRbKJMRipi883S8=" />
```

The code above works perfectly fine. How to translate this code in to this format:

```html
<select>
<c:forEach>
<option></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: If you want to make drop-down menu you should use <ul><li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think it should be like this.

```
<select name="floor">
<c:forEach items="floors" var="floor">
<option value="${floors.id}">${floors}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```